# jna maven error when building javacard applet

Tags: java, maven, applet, jna, javacard

I have attempted to run a build on a java program to convert it to a cap file for java cards. I however keep getting the following error:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find any version that matches net.java.dev.jna:jna:[3.2.5,4.0.0].
Searched in the following locations:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/maven-metadata.xml
http://releases.marmeladburk.fidesmo.com/net/java/dev/jna/jna/maven-metadata.xml
http://releases.marmeladburk.fidesmo.com/net/java/dev/jna/jna/
```

hope someone knows how to help. Thanks

## ==EDIT==

Now gradle build looks like this:

```
        apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'release'
apply plugin: 'fidesmo'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://releases.marmeladburk.fidesmo.com/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath  'com.fidesmo:gradle-fidesmo:0.1.10'
    }
}

javacard {
    cap {
        aid = "${fidesmoPrefix}:0x01"
        packageName = 'org.example.javacard.package'
        applet {
            aid = "${fidesmoPrefix}:0x01:0x01"
            className = 'Applet'
        }
        version = '1.0'
    }
}
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.github.townsfolk:gradle-release:1.2'
   }
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.6'

configurations {
    mavenDeploy
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://releases.marmeladburk.fidesmo.com/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.0.0' // alternative
    compile 'com.fidesmo:gradle-javacard:0.2.6'
    compile 'com.fidesmo:sec-client-core:0.2.2'
    compile 'com.fidesmo:sec-client-delivery:0.2.2'
    compile 'com.fidesmo:sec-client-local:0.2.2'
    compile 'io.github.jnasmartcardio:jnasmartcardio:0.2.6'
    compile ('io.github.jnasmartcardio:jnasmartcardio:0.2.4') {
    exclude group: "net.java.dev.jna", name: "jna"
  }
    compile 'jline:jline:2.13'
    runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    mavenDeploy 'org.kuali.maven.wagons:maven-s3-wagon:1.2.1'
}

group 'com.fidesmo'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            uniqueVersion = false
            configuration = configurations.mavenDeploy
            repository(url: "s3://${version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') ? 'snapshots' : 'releases'}.marmeladburk.fidesmo.com")
            pom.project {
                name 'Gradle fidesmo plugin'
                description 'Gradle plugin for easy development and deplyoment of java cardlets with the fidesmo service'
                url 'https://github.com/fidesmo/gradle-plugin'
                inceptionYear '2014'

                artifactId 'gradle-fidesmo'

                scm {
                    url 'https://github.com/fidesmo/gradle-fidesmo'
                    connection 'scm:https://github.com/fidesmo/gradle-fidesmo'
                    developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:fidesmo/gradle-fidesmo.git'
                }

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                        distribution 'repo'
                    }
                }

                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'yves'
                        name 'Yves Müller'
                        email 'yves.mueller@fidesmo.com'
                        organization 'Fidesmo AB'
                        organizationUrl 'http://fidesmo.com'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}
```

Comment: If you could attach some of your pom.xml that would definately help out.

Comment: I have looked at the project files and there is no pom.xml it is just a gradle wrapper

Comment: Is there anything worthy tto look at inside?

Comment: this is the exact git repo:https://github.com/fidesmo/gradle-fidesmo

Comment: I think the error comes from using an import jnasmartcardio

its git is here:
https://github.com/jnasmartcardio/jnasmartcardio/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but the build tool is trying to locate the version of the jna library based on the this xml file:

```
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/maven-metadata.xml
```

Inside the version it points to is the latest which is 4.3

```
<metadata>
<groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
<artifactId>jna</artifactId>
<versioning>
<latest>4.3.0</latest>
<release>4.3.0</release>
<versions>
<version>4.3.0</version>
</versions>
</metadata>
```

In your pom.xml the range is delcared as having a max version of 4.0.0:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>[3.2.5,4.0.0]</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Solution**

Change the to :

```
<version>[3.2.5,4.3.0]</version>
```

or (any particular version)

```
<version>4.0.0</version>
```

**In Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:[3.2.5,4.3.0]'
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.0.0' // alternative
    ...
}
```

**Update 2**

You may need to exclude the version from the parent:

```
compile ('io.github.jnasmartcardio:jnasmartcardio:0.2.4') {
    exclude group: "net.java.dev.jna", name: "jna"
  }
```

Comment: looks awesome but where do I find the xml

Comment: in the file you gave: github.com/jnasmartcardio/jnasmartcardio/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: if you use this as your parent .. then you have define the same dependency (with diffferent version) again in your pom.xml or build.gradle

Comment: it seems to download the dependancy straight from git. so is it best to try to override it in cradle.build how would I do this?

Comment: I cant find this line compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:[3.2.5,4.3.0]'

Comment: The try with single version 4.0.0

Comment: where is the parent

Comment: OK but remove the previous declaration of that dependency.

Comment: compile 'io.github.jnasmartcardio:jnasmartcardio:0.2.6'   remove this

Comment: still no luck... the search continues :)

Comment: I am the author of jnasmartcardio. I have released io.github.jnasmartcardio:jnasmartcardio:0.2.7 which explicitly depends on JNA 4.0.0 so that the empty http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/maven-metadata.xml should no longer be an issue. Please switch to jnasmartcardio 0.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug (this is my own small toolkit): for simple building of a JavaCard applet, you could try [ant-javacard](https://github.com/martinpaljak/ant-javacard) (no dependencies on anything)